# Broadcast receiver not triggering switchon method

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Why my broadcast receiver is only sending and creating notifications? 
I am trying to make it to switch on a device automatically 
but the device state is not changing for some reason.

It works if triggered in other classes but not in the broadcast.

please help me find the solution :)

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {


public boolean isFirstRun = false;  //Set this to true when user initially saves location

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

WemoActivity wemo = new WemoActivity();

private WeMoSDKContext mWeMoSDKContext = null;
private String DeviceName= "uuid:Socket-1_0-221412K1100F3A";



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    SharedPreferences mprefs = context.getSharedPreferences("First time", 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean isFirstRun = mprefs.getBoolean("First time", false);



    if (entering) {



        Toast.makeText(context,"in the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Entering");

    }
    else {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exiting");
         Toast.makeText(context,"out of the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }   


    sendNotification(context);


    //automatically switch device state when enter/leave region
    DeviceState(context.getApplicationContext(), entering);


    }








    public void sendNotification(Context context){
        // String extra=arg1.getExtras().getString("alert").toString();
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String message = "You are near your office/home.";

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,message, when);

        String title = "Proximity Alert!"; 

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
        notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1500;


        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);




        return;


    }





    private void DeviceState(Context context, boolean ON) {

        mWeMoSDKContext = new WeMoSDKContext(context);


mWeMoSDKContext.addNotificationListener(null);


        if(ON) {

              mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_ON, DeviceName);

        }else {
              mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(WeMoDevice.WEMO_DEVICE_OFF, DeviceName);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You mean broadcast broadcast receiver?

Comment: Had you enabled receiver in manifest file also?

Comment: I have defined it but not enabled it actually. Tho im using filters so I assume it doesnt need to be in manifest. The broadcast creates notifications but doesnt triger the device state. Do you still think the problem is in enabling it? Can you please just give an example also :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `BroadcastReceiver`, it depends upon the nature of the receiver.

Usually, just having that code in `onReceive()` is the right answer, particularly for manifest-registered receivers, as they only live for one broadcast.

If you are using `registerReceiver()` to register the receiver, you are welcome to create a constructor if you like.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did it know according to what you've said. but it is not triggering the method. please check the code if you can

Comment: @Abby: Since you do not seem to be registering the receiver, it will not receive anything.

Comment: i did enable it in the manifest if you mean that. can you please explain

Comment: @Abby: If you have it defined in the manifest, then apparently no broadcasts are being sent to that receiver. You may wish to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you provide your manifest and explain what is supposed to be sending broadcasts that your receiver will pick up.